# USB ethernet registered but not working

Tags: 12.04, usb, ethernet

I have a Cisco USB ethernet device plugged in to my 12.04lts.  It shows up in `lsusb` as `ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772` and `dmesg` notes it:

```
asix 5-1:1.0: eth1: register 'asix' at usb-000:06:00.0-1 ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet c0:c1:c0:94:f7:bd
```

(Updating...)  I see it listed in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` as...

```
# USB device 0x0b95:0x7720 (usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net"", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="c0:c1:c0:94:f7:bd", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

So USB has it, and part of the network system has it, but there is no `eth1` in `ifconfig` and `ifup eth1` says

```
Ignoring unknown interface eth1=eth1
```

How do I get it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into `/etc/network/interfaces` and add

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar problem that required a slightly different solution that I was able to reach thanks to the original poster.  I have several Cisco adapters that I am using with embedded systems and so, from time to time, each system will see different adapters.  Only one adapter is reliably detected.

What what I can tell, the problem is that each adapter gets it's own line in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` which specifies a name for the adapter e.g.

```
# USB device 0x0b95:0x7720 (usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ..., ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",...,KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"

# USB device 0x0b95:0x7720 (usb)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ..., ATTR{address}=="yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy",...,KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
```

Only the adapter with `NAME="eth1"` works happily.  Changing the name of all devices to `NAME=="eth1"` solves the problem.  This could be an issue on systems that could use multiple adapters.

Question:  Is this the only workaround? It feels very hacky.  I should also note that dmesg shows the same message as the original poster *always* showing eth1 regardless of the udev rules.