# USB 3.0 Asix AX88179 not working on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, upgrade, usb, kernel, 13.10

I upgraded from 13.04 to 13.10 and I had the AX88179 driver installed from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~qji/+archive/ax88179).
When I upgraded the USB 3.0 to Ethernet converter stopped working although it should be included in the kernel mainline starting from 3.9.
It is being recognized by the system but no connection is being made.
Here's the relevant verbose `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass       255 Vendor Specific Subclass
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x0b95 ASIX Electronics Corp.
  idProduct          0x1790 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 ASIX Elec. Corp.
  iProduct                2 AX88179
  iSerial                 3 00000000000001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           57
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              124mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              4 Network_Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              11
        bMaxBurst               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst               3
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0400  1x 1024 bytes
        bInterval               0
        bMaxBurst              15
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength           22
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  USB 2.0 Extension Device Capability:
    bLength                 7
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      2
    bmAttributes   0x00000002
      Link Power Management (LPM) Supported
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x00
    wSpeedsSupported   0x000e
      Device can operate at Full Speed (12Mbps)
      Device can operate at High Speed (480Mbps)
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat           1 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         101 micro seconds
Device Status:     0x000c
  (Bus Powered)
  U1 Enabled
  U2 Enabled
```

Unlike in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172655/usb-ethernet-registered-but-not-working) the device is not being recognized as an Ethernet device any more.
Here's the relevant output of dmseg:

```
dmesg | grep ASIX
[    3.238120] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[   61.907446] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[   84.772115] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[  192.615236] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[ 1146.200351] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.

dmesg | grep AX88179
[    3.238119] usb 4-2: Product: AX88179
[   61.907444] usb 4-2: Product: AX88179
[   84.772110] usb 4-1: Product: AX88179
[  192.615231] usb 4-2: Product: AX88179
[ 1146.200346] usb 4-2: Product: AX88179
```

The driver is not installed after the upgrade as far as I know.

Comment: The PPA above appears not to support ARM, any known source for a working ARM driver? (other than compiling from scratch).

Comment: @Noah considering this post was from 8 years ago, and that the PPA you refer to has not been updated in as many years, any data here is probably outdated.  You'll probably need to just bite the bullet and compile from source yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver works just fine unless Ubuntu goes into sleep mode. After recovering from sleep the driver simply stops to work.
The only workaround I found is to deactivate sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the ppa:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:qji/ax88179
# since there is no source for soucy, replace it with raring:
sed s/saucy/raring/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qji-ax88179-saucy.list>/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qji-ax88179-raring.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qji-ax88179-saucy.list
aptitude update
aptitude install ax88179 
reboot
```

---

*It worked **one time**, only the first time after the first reboot it worked. since then I get failure errors in syslog.
It works on the laptop of my friend though, with parabola linux.
I will buy another adapter ;)*