# AX88179 Ethernet adapter not working properly

Tags: networking, usb

I recently bought an adapter with the ASIX AX88179 chip in it. The adapter seems to work, but after about one minute it gets terribly slow. I have already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312847/how-to-install-or-troubleshoot-a-usb-3-0-ax88179-gigabit-ethernet-adapter) and [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376864/usb-3-0-asix-ax88179-not-working-on-ubuntu-13-10) to no avail.
Also, I cannot compile the driver from [the ASIX website](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=ProductList&PLine=71&PSeries=112) as `make` simply fails with:

```
/home/christopher/Schreibtisch/AX88179_178A/ax88179_178a.c:55:6: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
      ^
/home/christopher/Schreibtisch/AX88179_178A/ax88179_178a.c:55:19: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
  " " __TIME__ " " __DATE__ "\n"
                   ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target '/home/christopher/Schreibtisch/AX88179_178A/ax88179_178a.o' failed
```

(I'm running Ubuntu 14.10.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a compiler flag to the EXTRA_CFLAGS variable in the Makefile, like so:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS = -DEXPORT_SYMTAB -Wno-error=date-time
```

Possibly there are better ways to do this.  If you want the ethernet to work, look here: https://github.com/geoffreytran/AX88179_178A.