# Inateck USB 3.0 Hub+Gigabit Ethernet Adapter with Acer c720

Tags: drivers, usb, ethernet, acer

I'm not sure if this is where I should be asking this, so if this is the wrong place please let me know and I can post elsewhere.
I am running [HugeGreenBug's Ubuntu 14.10 for Acer c720](https://www.distroshare.com/distros/get/50/) with coreboot (kernel 3.18.7) and I am trying to get my [Inateck HBU3VL3-4 USB 3.0 Hub+Gigabit Ethernet adapter](http://www.inateck.com/inateck-hbu3vl3-4-usb3-0-hub-gigabit-ethernet-network-adapter/info/) to work. The drivers from their website do not compile, however I have been able to get it to work using the directions in the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601627/ax88179-ethernet-adapter-not-working-properly) . Now onto the actual problem.
The device will work in the USB 2.0 slot.

The output of lsub is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e056 Foxconn / Hon Hai
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c67 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And the output of dmesg is:

```
[ 1393.834290] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
[ 1393.964154] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812
[ 1393.964158] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1393.964161] usb 1-5: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1393.964163] usb 1-5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 1393.964677] hub 1-5:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1393.964993] hub 1-5:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1395.562267] usb 1-5.1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[ 1395.668078] usb 1-5.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790
[ 1395.668083] usb 1-5.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1395.668085] usb 1-5.1: Product: AX88179
[ 1395.668087] usb 1-5.1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[ 1395.668089] usb 1-5.1: SerialNumber: 0000000000008B
[ 1395.992027] ax88179_178a 1-5.1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-5.1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:23:56:1c:21:03
[ 1397.345814] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 1399.234172] ax88179_178a 1-5.1:1.0 eth0: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
[ 1399.240936] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

As you can see it is recognized as a USB 2.0 hub and I am able to use the ethernet and the usb ports. But when I plug it into my USB 3.0 slot the usb ports don't seem to be powered, or are very weakly powered, the ethernet is not recognized, and the outputs change.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0489:e056 Foxconn / Hon Hai
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c67 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg:

```
[ 1821.861482] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd
[ 1821.991012] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2812
[ 1821.991017] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1821.991019] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[ 1821.991021] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[ 1821.991615] hub 1-2:1.0: USB hub found
[ 1821.991953] hub 1-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.